I spilled coffee on a marquetry inlay table
My table has a ring of lighter wood inset, and coffee has got into it under the French Polish. Milk and sugar :/
There is sliiiiight discolouration where the coffee has run into the grain. I would assume to just leave it? It’s a mid century or 40s piece.
And then, how do I seal it to prevent further mishaps?

Hi, welcome to StackExchange. There are problems with the form of your Q for the SE model. StackExchange strives to be a place where concrete Answers are provided for concrete Questions after doing your own research to try to solve the problem for yourself. Plus, the format is as much as possible for there to be only one query per Q. "I would assume to just leave it?" From the Help, "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."
